# Microsoft Visual C++ 0x80 reading into char from ASCII file

Tags: visual-c++, character-encoding, ascii, hex

I'm trying to read a character represented by the hex value 0x80 from a file and then when writing to another file, ignore this character. However, if I check this character with a simple command, such as:

```
if(int(c1) == 0x80)
  str += "";
```

The character still ends up written to the string and eventually written to my file. I've done a little bit of research and I think it may have something to do with signed/unsigned characters and Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 using signed character, putting 0x80 outside the bounds. When I insert breakpoints into my program when I know a variable contains this character and mouseover it tells me the value of the character is 0. I'm now sure what this means, but when I started using it as a test `c1 == 0` it still ends up writing the character to the file. Oddly enough it shows up as a block character 0x80 in Notepad++ instead of the Euro sign (how it shows up in the input and output files when its not caught. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you surmised, it's probably sign-extending the number. This might work:

```
if((int(c1) & 0xff)== 0x80)
  str += "";
```

Comment: This works, but so does just testing if the character is equal to -128. It was wrapping around. I discovered it by watching the input stream.

Comment: sure, that would be more efficient.